# Why types at System.Numerics shows empty at Reflector?

Tags: c#, biginteger

I opened System.Numerics at reflector to study how it works.

But all methods at BigInteger and Complex are empty. Why? How can this works?

Comment: I was able to examine the code.

Comment: I will try. But mine is version 6

Comment: I updated, but dont work. Method bodys just have ".maxstack 8" (IL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I openning assembly from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

But this is right path:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

Why exists fakes assemblies?

Answer (score 2):

Get the latest reflector here: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/
(I'm able to view it fine using the current release, free version)

There are some improvements to support previously un-reflectable (new word?) code each release, being able to view it now is just the result of a bug fix really.

Comment: And if you find code that the latest version can't process, try changing the language to MSIL.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the answer to this other question for more detail:

[Why does System.Numerics.BigInteger not have a Parse method in Silverlight 4.0, but does in .Net 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628955/why-does-system-numerics-biginteger-not-have-a-parse-method-in-silverlight-4-0-b)